# Upon clicking Apple watch provisioning Profile got - Apple Configurator 2 cannot open files in the “Provisioning Profile” format

Tags: swift, provisioning-profile, apple-configurator

I tried installing a Apple Watch provisioning profile in my mac, but that throws an error saying "Apple Configurator 2 cannot open files in the “Provisioning Profile” format." Any ideas in this please?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Found a solution -
1. Connect your iPhone and double click it to select.
2. Select 'Profile' on left menu options. 
3. Drag provisioning Profile into the space and close the window on successful addition. 
4. Go back and double click .provisioingprofile.
5. Check back in Xcode project area for profile.

You're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode Provisioning Profiles are created automatically on your apple account.
You don not need to do it manually.

check [here](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/) their will be the provisioning profile for your bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below is copy of my comment in the question. Just separating for visibility.

Found a solution -

1. Connect your iPhone and double click it to select from the Apple Configurator app.
2. Select 'Profile' on left menu options.
3. Drag provisioning Profile into the space and close the window on successful addition. You may need to overwrite the item already there.
4. Go back and double click .provisioingprofile.
5. Check back in Xcode project area for profile. You're good to go!